# Temporal and spatial coherence

Tags: physics

What kind of results (is the interference pattern formed, is the total throughput intensity changed) I have in experiment about coherence if:

1)Rc more than R and t less than tc
2)Rc more than R and t more than tc
3)Rc less R and t less than tc
4)Rc less and t more than tc

where Rc and tc are the spatial and temporal coherence lengths of the beam (in this case a laser)

Comment: This really belongs on [physices.stackexchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com), but I'll bet there's a standard answer...

Answer (score 0):

In all the four cases the Interference pattern is not formed.
For an interference to occur both the sources must be have spatial and temporal coherence.

Refer this link:
http://www.phys.ttu.edu/~huang24/Teaching/Phys2401/LectureNotes/Ch37A.pdf

http://www.phys.uconn.edu/~gibson/Notes/Section5_2/Sec5_2.htm

http://www.phys.uconn.edu/~gibson/Notes/Section5_3/Sec5_3.htm